# Daily change with zoo

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I am trying to compare volatility of two time series, looking at things such as:

- average daily change in series A vs. B
- largest daily change in series A vs. B
- sd of daily change is series A vs. B
- largest difference between series A and B

I'm new to R, but everyone seems to be recommending zoo for time series. I searched through and through and there is not a single tutorial on how to find day on day change...

For now I have this:

```
series<-c("A","B")  
dateStart="01-jan-15"
DateEnd=format(Sys.Date(),format="%d-%b-%y")
dfa=getMyData(series[1],dateStart,DateEnd)
dfb=getMyData(series[2],dateStart,DateEnd)
df <-merge(dfa,dfb,by="date")  
df$date<-as.Date(df$date)
df=rename(df, c("price.x"="A"))
df=rename(df, c("price.y"="B"))
df=df[ , !names(df) %in% c("series.x","series.y")]  
df$Difference=df$A-df$B
abc <- read.zoo(df)
summary(abc)
```

Am I missing something very simple? Surely a package made for time series analysis should have a one function solution to adding daily change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first create the data

```
z.index = as.Date(12550:12554)
z1 = zoo(seq(1,3,6,4,3), order.by = z.index)
z2 = zoo(seq(2,7,4,8,3), order.by = z.index)
```

average daily change in series A vs. B - difference between the two

```
mean(diff(z1)) - mean(diff(z2))
```

largest daily change in series A vs. B - largest in each series

```
max(diff(z1)); max(diff(z2))
```

sd of daily change is series A vs. B

```
sd(diff(z1)); sd(diff(z2))
```

largest difference between series A and B - if you mean absolute difference

```
max(abs(z1 - z2));
```